# What is this spring white-flowering shrub?

Tags: identification

This delicate-looking shrub has been in flower for a couple of weeks, although I suspect it would normally flower later; we've had an exceptionally mild spring here in Shropshire, UK.

I've seen it used in a garden hedge, but the top had these long spires, too. The tiny flowers (barely 5mm / 1/4in) are very lightly scented later in the day. [image: Picture taken 29th March 2019]

The second picture is from almost exactly a year ago, which was very cold. You can see it's quite well-estabalished. We moved to this house in September 2017.
[image: Picture taken 23rd March 2018]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is a Spiraea, most likely S. arguta, common name Bridal Wreath. You're right, it usually flowers more towards May  than end of March, but, as you say, despite a couple of cold snaps, we've had a pretty mild winter and a very warm February in the UK, which has meant that lots of shrubs which don't normally flower till May are already flowering. The flowering looks a little sparse, but if you cut it back at the wrong time, that, or the fact its flowering too early, could explain that. Any pruning/cutting back that's necessary should be carried out as soon as the flowers have faded so it has time to put on new growth during the spring/summer which will flower next year, so cut back as hard as you need to so you don't have to cut it again, apart from possibly a stray branch or two later in the season. Otherwise, it has no special requirements.  Images here https://www.classicroses.co.uk/spiraea-arguta.html

Comment: Thank you. Your comments about pruning make complete sense; we moved into our house with its rather overgrown garden in late September 2017. We had some overgrown shrubs and conifers removed and several other shrubs pruned right back. This was one of them and I don't think it flowered at all last year. There are masses of buds still to open lower down the branches, so I don't think it's reached peak flowering yet.

p.s. I did up-vote your answer, but even though it's my own question, my vote doesn't count as my reputation isn't high enough yet.